# How accurate are altimeters?

Tags: sensor, robotics, uav

I'm building a quadrocopter and would like to prevent drift using a down facing camera. To do this properly, I need to get the height of the drone from the ground. Obviously the ground can vary, so maybe something like radar would be an idea, but I was wondering... how accurate are altimeters (electronic) these days?

Comment: Why do you need to know the height?  Because the speed scenery moves by will vary by height?  I think that could be compensated for by a feedback controller, though, couldn't it?  It's just seeking to minimize the movement of the ground, not calculate speed from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you base your design loosely on the Parrot drone, they use a downward facing ultrasonic rangefinder.  I'm not sure of the exact brand, but it looks like a PING or Devantech rangefinder.

Different model numbers vary in their range and accuracy.  Most are in the 2-5 meter range and have an accuracy of about 2-5cm.  Obviously, the more you pay for the sensor will determine how accurate the sensor is.

Both [Acroname](http://acroname.com/robotics/parts/c_Sensors.html) and [Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/84) have good selections of ultrasonic rangefinders.

You may be able to also use a different type of rangefinding technology.  I have seen IR and laser rangefinders used in many robotics applications.  For a quadrotor, the ultrasonic rangefinder seems to be the best in terms of cost and performance.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the great answer; ultrasound looks to be the way to go. I will use an altimeter as well, so I can get a larger range of measurements (but less accurate ones obviously).

Answer (score 2):

The answer effectively boils down to two questions:
"How Much do you want to spend"
"What are your size requirements?

Realistically, there are three way to measure altitude without looking at the ground below:

- GPS - Not very precise (~3m), unless you know people in the military.
- Inertial Measurement - Expensive, if you want decent precision. Theoretically could work anywhere.
- Barometry - Requires an air column. Sparkfun [has one](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8128) that claims a resolution of 9 cm.

Comment: A barometric sensor with a 9cm resolution sounds too good to be true, and I think it should be taken with more than a pinch of salt. First, they're absolute pressure sensors, so they have to be recalibrated for height with changing air pressure (weather). Then this is _resolution_, which means the theoretical height (pressure) change represented by 1 LSB. That's not _accuracy_, however. That depends on a number of factors, like linearity, and noise. If your LSB is drowned by 5 bits of noise your effective resolution reduces to 3m. Which would still be very good by any standard.

Comment: GPS note: actually, there's a second way to get precise height out of GPS: sit still for a day or so. Not useful for the project at hand, but the technique is used by folks like the National Geodetic Survey in some of their equipment.

Comment: You should be able to get down to ~1m with a single-ended GPS setup, assuming a relatively decent sensor (I believe that the uBlox line is pretty good for the cost).  If a higher degree of precision is necessary for GPS measurements, you can move to a differential GPS setup.  This is VERY expensive, on the scale of hobby projects, but very accurate (sub-decimeter or centimeter accuracy, depending on algorithm used)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will definitely take these into account when designing the stability system.

Comment: The 3m figure is applicable for positional accuracy in latitude/longitude plane, but not for altitude.